# How to create a conv1d for an array of multiple dimensions

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

Here is my problem :

Suppose I am studying cancerous cells,
To simplify let's say I am watching 1 tumor.
each tumor will have its average oversize cells rate, average abnormal shape cells rate
I am using data taken once every month over 12 months
What I was thinking was having for each tumor an array of tuples:

```
[(0.2,0.3),(0.3,0.3)..until I have 12]
```

Here is some sample code for this question :

```
dataset = []

for i in range(1000):
    train = []
    for j in range(0,12):
        train.append((np.random.rand(),np.random.rand()))
    dataset.append(train)

model = keras.Sequential([
        layers.Conv1D(filters=4, kernel_size=2, activation='relu',input_shape=tf.shape(dataset[0])),
        layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
        layers.Dense(1)])


model.predict(dataset)
```

When I try to do model.predict() I get :

```
Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 2 from 1 for  '{{node conv1d/conv1d}} = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], explicit_paddings=[], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true](conv1d/conv1d/ExpandDims, conv1d/conv1d/ExpandDims_1)' with input shapes: [?,1,1,2], [1,2,2,4].
```

Do you know what I am doing wrong here? I tried looking at tf and keras documentation and can build basic perceptron, but maybe I should not use an array of tuples and use something else. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

keras/tensorflow doesn't handle tuple data format. the simplest data format accepted by keras is numpy arrays. Following your code snippet, this is simply to impose

```
dataset = []

for i in range(1000):
    train = []
    for j in range(0,12):
        train.append([np.random.rand(), np.random.rand(), np.random.rand()]) # don't use tuple
    dataset.append(train)
    
dataset = np.asarray(dataset) # convert to numpy array
print(dataset.shape)

model = Sequential([
        layers.Conv1D(filters=4, kernel_size=2, activation='relu',
               input_shape=dataset.shape[1:]),
        layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
        layers.Dense(1)])

model.predict(dataset).shape
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, let me try and I will mark your answer as the best answer for this problem.

Comment: Looks like I also didn't convert into numpy array. Awesome thank you so much!

Comment: Hi Marco, I edited my answer to only have 2 elements in the array which was what I intended. Am I correct by saying that when i set kernel_size = 2 it will take 2 points each having the 2 dimensions specified and do the conv. If I was saying kernel_size=3 it will take 3 points each having dimensions = 2 and so on?

Comment: 2 or 3 points my answer is still valid... yes what you said is correct

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to point out I edited the post, thanks for your answer, greatly appreciated.